# AD7683 + stm32f407 + SPI

Tags: stm32, spi

I have stm32f407discovery and ADC AD7683

I try to read one 16-bit sample value as 3x 8-bit SPI value and use a bit shifts, but I receive only '1' in all 3 spi value.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or where the problem is ?

```
#define CS_LOW GPIOA->BSRRH = GPIO_BSRR_BS_15;
#define CS_HIGH GPIOA->BSRRL = GPIO_BSRR_BS_15;

uint8_t DataHigh = 0;
uint8_t DataMid = 0;
uint8_t DataLow = 0;
uint16_t result = 0;
uint16_t res = 0;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void SPI_in()
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_SPI3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_SPI3);
    //GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_SPI3);

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15; // cs
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI3, ENABLE);
    SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_128;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_High;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_RxOnly;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;

    SPI_Init(SPI3, &SPI_InitStructure);
    //SPI_SSOutputCmd(SPI3, ENABLE);
    SPI_Cmd(SPI3, ENABLE);
    SPI_NSSInternalSoftwareConfig(SPI3, SPI_NSSInternalSoft_Set);

    CS_HIGH;
}
void TIM_in()
{
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2,ENABLE);
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_Init;
    TIM_Init.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_Init.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_Init.TIM_Period = 10;
    TIM_Init.TIM_Prescaler = 2000-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_Init);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
    {
        CS_LOW;
        //while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) == SET) {}
        if (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == SET)
        {
            DataHigh = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
            //while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) {}
            DataMid = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
            //while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) {}
            DataLow = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
        }
        CS_HIGH;
        result = (DataHigh << 14) | (DataMid << 6) | (DataLow >> 2);
        res = result >> 4;
        DAC->DHR12R1 = res;
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DAC_in()
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitDAC;
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_DAC, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitDAC.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_4;
    GPIO_InitDAC.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AIN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitDAC);

    DAC_InitTypeDef DAC_In;
    DAC_In.DAC_LFSRUnmask_TriangleAmplitude = DAC_LFSRUnmask_Bit0;
    DAC_In.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OutputBuffer_Enable;
    DAC_In.DAC_Trigger = DAC_Trigger_None;
    DAC_In.DAC_WaveGeneration = DAC_WaveGeneration_None;

    DAC_Init(DAC_Channel_1, &DAC_In);
    DAC_Cmd(DAC_Channel_1, ENABLE);
}

int main(void)
{
    SPI_in();
    TIM_in();
    DAC_in();
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is value for SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_128 ?
shematic connection?

Comment: That's a constant defined by the STM32F4 SPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3) function isn't blocking and merely returns the value currently stored in the SPI3 data register. You need to load a byte into the SPI3 data register to start the SPI peripheral sending that byte, you then need to wait until the RXNE flag is set, and you will then have your piece of data, like so:

```
CS_LOW;
SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI3, 0xFF); //Send dummy byte to start SPI transaction
while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
DataHigh = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
DataMid = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI3, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
DataLow = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI3);
CS_HIGH;

//Do stuff with data
```